# Is the electromagnetic component of a photon from a positively charged nucleus any different from one produced by an electron?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, gamma-rays

Photons are produced as exchange particles when electrons change their orbit and we know from Maxwell that there is an electric and magnetic component to the waveform. However, if a photon is created by the decay of a positively charged particle, e.g. a gamma ray photon from a nucleus during radioactive decay, does this cause the electric component of its waveform to be of opposite polarity?

Comment: The picture that bosons are somehow second class citizens that are "only" doing the force exchange between the "real" fermionic matter fields is misleading. One can't even formulate a self-consistent theory of either without the other. At the core of your question is a different misunderstanding, though. A single photon doesn't produce an electric or a magnetic field component. That would take the average of many photons. The macroscopic fields are merely expectation values of the microscopic theory.

Comment: Your question is a very interesting one and I think a very important to. But the chance to remove it from on hold] is vanishing small. Anyway, to give an answer is not easy. I'll try to exchange my thoughts with you.        1. Photons are indivisible portions of energy, they get emitted from excited electrons as well as from excited protons. It is possible to emit photons one by one and than they are countable one by one. CouriousOne's comment arises from a different view, in which exist a overall electromagnetic field and the energy portions are disturbances so of this field. Not my point. ->

Comment: How it is possible to derive about the photons structure? It is not possible to have a direct measurement of the electric and the magnetic field components of the photon, the energy content is to small, the frequency to high and the velocity infinite big. But since the invention of radio waves we are able to derive from the "behaviour" of radio waves to the photons nature. Radio waves arise from accelerated electrons in an antenna rod. The get accelerated from a wave generator which produces a electric sinusoidal potential between the ends of the antenna rod.

Comment: It is measurable that the electric field of the accelerated electrons induces a magnetic field which is perpendicular to the rod and this magnetic field partially does not induce an electric field back to the rod but into the free space around the rod. An EM wave is born with its electric and its magnetic field component.    2. It is well known that a moving through a magnetic field electron (not parallel to the field) gets deflected (Lorentz force) in a unsymmetrical way. If you somehow define that your thumb shows the ..

Comment: ...direction of the electrons movement and the second finger shows the direction (defined as a convention) of the magnetic field than your middle finger, directed perpendicular to both the second finger and the thumb, shows you the direction of the deflection. For protons as well as for positrons (the anti-particle of the electron) the direction of the deflection will be opposite.     3. Now the main point. The electric and the magnetic field component of a photon are oriented to each other by 90° and both are oriented (in the vacuum) by 90° To the direction of propagation.

Comment: A sketch about the photons field components see [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Участник:HolgerFiedler/Photons#/media/File:Photon_Spin_%2B1.PNG)

Comment: All this processes of photon emission and Lorentz force have to do with two the electrons intrinsic spin and the electrons magnetic dipole moment. Let say that's they are by convention orientated parallel, than this two properties for protons as well as positrons are oriented anti-parallel. This different properties of orientation led to different shift in the magnetic due to the electric field component, compare the above links sketch with [this on](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Участник:HolgerFiedler/Photons#/media/File:Photon_Spin_-1.PNG).

Comment: From all above mentioned I conclude that you are right with your question and the shift of the electric and magnetic field components are the solution. BTW this are the two only possible variations of the photon and they called the intrinsic spin.

Comment: Thanks HolgerFiedler, so it looks from the images you have posted that the magnetic component changes phase by 180 degrees. This is what I thought, but as you say, the difference is probably is undetectable.

Comment: @A.Kestner Please use "@" for a comment you will address to somebody.

Comment: @A.Kestner perhaps [calcite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) will show different behaviour for EM radiation from accelerated electrons and for accelerated positrons. This would be an indirect advice for different spins of EM radiation electrons and protons.